# Correct mysql structure

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a two variants of DB structure.

**First:**
[image]

Here is one comments table, and two special table 'news_comments' and 'photos_comments' which connect comment with material.

**Second variants:**
[image]

Here only 3 tables, without connector tables, but table comments have a special field 'type', which will be used with query. 
For example: `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE type = 'news';`

**Question:**
I don't know which variant is better. I think second, but is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless a single comment can apply to more than one photo and/or news item, the 2nd option better represents and "enforces" the logical concept in data. But, I'd recommend replacing `photos_id` and `news_id` with `item_id`, which holds *either* a `photos_id` *or* a `news_id`, and changing `type` from a `varchar` to an `enum('news','photo')`.

Again, this is under the assumption that any given comment applies to one news item or one photo, never both, and never more than one (which is usually how commenting systems work, eh?).

Comment: How can one comment be connected with news and photos? Every material have own comment system and they are separate.

Comment: @user2058653 Is that a technical or a philosophical question?

Comment: @user2058653 Well, the commonly-understood concept of a comment usually *shouldn't* be attached to more than one "thing." Hence, my answer. *But*, I could *conceive* of a system wherein comments made on a particular page are loosely associated with every "thing" on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution to me appears to support a many to many relationship, and would be my first choice.

The 2nd only supports a single photo for a comment and a single news item for a comment.